# How can i sort an arrays of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby

this is the code i tried to sort it by name,email,country,comments.first i tried sorting by names

```
array_of_hashes=[
  {"Name"=>"Akash","Email"=>"akash85@gmail.com","Country"=>"India",'Comments'=>"9898984523"},
  {"Email"=>"rahul@hotmail.com","Country"=>"Srilanka","Name"=>"Rahul"},
  {"Country"=>"India", "Comments"=>"3455358782","Email"=>"veera@gmail.com","Name"=>"Veera"},
  {"Name"=>"Akash","Country"=>"India",   "Email"=>"akash37@yahoo.com", "Comments"=>"8898788932"}
]
puts array_of_hashes.sort_by { |element| element.keys(&:Name)}
```

but the displayed output is not as i expected,it prints the same which i mentioned above.

i expected to code the final output should be like this

```
Name Email Country Comments

Akash akash37@live.com India 8898788932
Akash akash85@gmail.com India 9898984523
Rahul rahul@hotmail.com Srilanka
Veera veera@gmail.com India 3455358782
```

Help me to resolve these.Thanks in advance!

Comment: "its not worked" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: meant the output is not as i expected ,which displays the hash without sorting by names accordingly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
not_a_hash = [
  {"Name"=>"Akash","Email"=>"akash85@gmail.com","Country"=>"India",'Comments'=>"9898984523"},
  {"Email"=>"rahul@hotmail.com","Country"=>"Srilanka","Name"=>"Rahul"},
  {"Country"=>"India", "Comments"=>"3455358782","Email"=>"veera@gmail.com","Name"=>"Veera"},
  {"Name"=>"Akash","Country"=>"India",   "Email"=>"akash37@yahoo.com", "Comments"=>"8898788932"}
]

sorted_values = not_a_hash.map{|h| h.values_at("Name", "Email", "Country", "Comments")}.sort
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at what `element.keys(&:Name)` evaluates to in the block that you're passing to `#sort_by`. All methods in Ruby can be given a block, you can pass it even if the method doesn't use it. `Hash#keys` doesn't use the block so `element.keys(&:Name)` is the same as `element.keys` and you end up trying to sort by the array `['Name', 'Email', 'Country', 'Comments']`.

If you want to sort by the name, say so:

```
hash.sort_by { |element| element['Name'] }
```

Keep in mind that your keys are strings so you want `element['Name']` rather than `element[:Name]`. I'd also recommend that you don't call your array of hashes `hash`, that's a little confusing.